# Contour Filling using open CV or skimage?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm trying to find the total area of glue regions in this digital microscopy image.

I have the problem that I can't seem to fill the regions inside, I can however succesfully get the contours of the glue regions.

Here is my code so far:

```
from skimage.io import imread
from scipy.ndimage import distance_transform_edt
from skimage.color import rgb2hed
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage.morphology import opening, closing, disk
import numpy as np
from scipy import fftpack
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
import cv2

# Read the image
im = imread("10C_11_lugol_smaller.jpg")

# Show the image

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im)

# Convert image from RGB to HED
hed = rgb2hed(im)

# Remove Stripes
im_fft = fftpack.fft2(hed[:, :, 0])
plt.figure()
plt.imshow((np.abs(im_fft)).astype(np.uint8), norm=LogNorm())
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Fourier transform')

keep_fraction = 0.1
im_fft2 = im_fft.copy()
# Set r and c to be the number of rows and columns of the array
r, c = im_fft2.shape
im_fft2[int(r * keep_fraction):int(r * (1 - keep_fraction))] = 0
im_fft2[:, int(c * keep_fraction):int(c * (1 - keep_fraction))] = 0
plt.figure()
plt.imshow((np.abs(im_fft2)).astype(np.uint8), norm=LogNorm())
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Filtered Spectrum')

# Reconstructing
im_new = fftpack.ifft2(im_fft2).real
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im_new)
plt.title('Reconstructed Image')

# Creating the Otsu Threshold on the first layer
t = threshold_otsu(im_new)
mask = im_new > t
mask = closing(opening(mask, disk(1)), disk(1))

# Show the result of the thresholding
fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(im)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(mask)

# Filling the contour

cv_image = img_as_ubyte(mask)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
res = cv2.morphologyEx(cv_image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(res, plt.cm.gray)
plt.title('Filled Contours')

# Apply the distance transform on the results
distance = distance_transform_edt(mask)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(distance)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

Can someone please help :(

Thanks in advance for reading!

[Results So Far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGwaq.jpg)

Comment: Your objects are not closed loops. They have breaks. You need to find some way to close the loops. I do not see any code for getting contours.

Comment: @fmw42 In the #  Filling the contours section I use the OPEN morph function to find the bubbles of glue

I've tried to use also this:

```
contour, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for cnt in contour:
     cv2.drawContours(mask, cnt, -1, (0, 255, 255), -1)

```
Both seem to result in the same thing